# How to redirect stderr in busybox?

Tags: io-redirection, busybox, stderr

I have

```
BusyBox v1.27.1 (2017-08-03 03:14:35 CEST) built-in shell (ash)
```

on router. I found a weird issue:

```
root@DD-WRT:/# echo -n "Hi" 2>/dev/null
-sh: 2: Invalid argument
```

Seems I cannot redirect stderr. Is this a common known thing? Or a bug? Is there some alternative to redirecting stderr?

Comment: tried with busybox v1.27.1 (https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.27.1-i686/ ) and works for me, not sure where to grab dd-wrt's version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a DD-WRT bug, and it was fixed in August 2019.

- A `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` parameter to the `fcntl()` function has been available since Linux 2.6.24 in 2008.
- Busybox's Almquist shell started using it ten years later in 2018, for parts of enacting shell redirections.
- But the Linux 2.6 supplied in DD-WRT on some routers was Linux 2.6.**23**.

The fix was to backport support for `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` into DD-WRT's Linux 2.6.

## Further reading

- doktornotor (2017-03-26). *[Busybox - Invalid argument since r31533 Broadcom K2.6](https://svn.dd-wrt.com/ticket/5784)*.  DD-WRT bug #5784.
- Denys Vlasenko (2018-03-30).  *[ash: use `F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC` and `O_CLOEXEC`](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?id=60fb98e51d11ed45bbc836eb28a2539ba3ab76f7)*.  Busybox git.